# pass receiver struct by reference

Tags: go, struct

I need a function to return a struct that was passed into the function by the caller.  The struct will be different each time the function is called.

I'm using and ORM postgres driver "github.com/go-pg/pg".
As I understand it, ORM requires the struct be defined before calling the .Query() which populates the struct with data from the database.

```
func PgSql(user User, statement string)(output []string, err error) {

_, err = db.Query(&users, `SELECT * FROM standard_lookup WHERE pkid_ = 'STATE|AFKDZ'`)

}
```

The results will be in the user struct.  However, I need this struct defined in a different package and passed into this function.    Is there some sort of interface magic I can do here?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your issue is here, but if you want the caller to pass in a struct and have its values populated, the function should take a `*User` instead of a `User`, and pass that pointer directly through to `db.Query()`.

Comment: thanks, sorry I am not clear.  the struct user needs to be dynamic.  The caller needs to define what the sql results will looks like.  If the statement it passes in is like "select field1, field2, from table;" then the struct user will need to have field1 and field2 defined in it.  (each field is the column name in the database).

Comment: the problem is that the signature will be different each time this pgSql func is called.  the struct is defined out of scope in a different package.    The way go is it requires the struct be defined in the pgsql which makes it not as flexible as I need it to be.   I'm wondering what I can do do work around this limitiation

Comment: The first argument should be of type `interface{}` then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a different type to be passed in each time, your argument needs to be an interface and a pointer to the struct to be populated needs to be passed into that interface:

```
func PgSql(dest interface{}, statement string)(output []string, err error) {
    _, err = db.Query(dest, statement)
    // handle error
}

func main() {
    var user User
    _, err := PgSql(&user, `SELECT * FROM standard_lookup WHERE pkid_ = 'STATE|AFKDZ'`)
    // handle error
}
```

Note that within the `PgSql` function, you're passing the `dest` interface variable directly, *not* a pointer to it.  That's because that interface already *holds* a pointer (it's called with `&user`), so you don't need to pass a reference to the interface, just the value of the interface (which itself is a reference to, in this code, the `user` variable in `main()`).

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for. THANK YOU SO MUCH. I knew it was an interface I needed and thank you for explaining the correct way to reference it.   this made my day!    Have a good one yourself internet friend!